# How to mock out an attribute on an APIView for unit tests in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have an APIView that hits an external API itself to aggregate results. I've defined it as such:

```
class SampleView(APIView):
    api = query_api()

    def get(self, request, id):
        result = self.api.query(id)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I have a mocked out API to make this testable without having that external API as a dependency in my unit tests.  I would like to do something like `SampleView.api = fake_api()` before running unit tests.

How do I swap out a single attribute like this, in order to replace a concrete class with a mocked out one for unit testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't find any significant advantage of having `api` object in as class attribute. It doesn't belong to the view,

You can instanciate `object` inside get request. By doing this mocking is straight forward.

```
In [21]: class ExternalApi(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("APIService")
   ....:

In [22]: class MockedExternalApi(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("FakeApiService")
   ....:

In [23]: def query_api():
    return ExternalApi()
   ....:

In [24]: class MyView(object):
    def get(self, request):
        api = ExternalApi(23)
        return "Something"
   ....:

In [25]: @mock.patch('__main__.ExternalApi')
def test(mocked_api):
    mocked_api.return_value = MockedExternalApi()

    view = MyView()

    assert view.get({}) == "Something"
   ....:

In [26]: test()
FakeApiService
```

Also you can lookup `settings` variable inside `query_api` and return Proper object depending on the scenario.